# VBA open Hyperlink into a new instance of browser

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I create one list in excel From A2 to A22,
in each cell of this range I've one Hyperlink, and I need to loop all cell and open her link.
Simple?!?!? more or less, for me is to easy wrote the code than this tread:

```
Sub PlayAllVideo()
For Each cl In Range("A2:A22")
    cl.Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True
Next cl
End Sub
```

But my code work wrong, for play all record I need one instance of Browser, not all tab in the same instance.
the parameter `NewWindow` add one tab, if I want open a new instance of browser how I can to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around browsers that reuse tabs or create new tabs, simply create your own instance of IE each time like this:

```
Sub PlayAllVideo()
    Dim IE As Object

    For Each cl In Range("A2:A22")
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        'It is generally advisable to avoid using Select and ActiveCell
        'cl.Select
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate cl.Hyperlinks.item(1).Address
    Next cl
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer of Tim is very good, I mark it.
for one error I voted down the answer, how I can change to useful ??

Comment: This code works without any errors for me. What's the error you are getting? And what's not useful?? Your question was how to open each link in its own instance of IE. This does exactly that. If my answer is not useful, redefine your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be on the browser side. I tried using Firefox and Internet Explorer and the issue was resolved after changing browser settings. However, the solution isn't perfect as it always opens new windows regardless of the NewWindow setting in VBA.

Assuming you are using Firefox, i encountered the same behavior till I turned off the "Open new windows in a new tab instead" option. Afterwards, each hyperlink was opened in a separate window.

For Internet Explorer, under internet Options > Tabs Settings > Open Links From Other Programs was changed to A New Window instead of a New Tab.

Comment: This will probably work, however it would require everyone who used the workbook to change this setting. Plus, changing this setting will affect the default behavior of every application that interacts with the browser.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, this isn't a very good method. Your method is much better! Didn't think of creating a new IE window altogether.